How to calculate the total volume of bullish candles in each first session, and only for the candles within that session in Pine Script?
I'm using Pine Script to develop an indicator on TradingView. I want to calculate the total volume of all bullish candles in each first session, and only for the candles within that session.
I have tried using the following code:
//@version=5
indicator("Enhanced Period Signal", overlay=true)

firstSession = ta.change(time('D')) or ta.change(time('D'))[1] or ta.change(time('D'))[2] or ta.change(time('D'))[3]

bullishCandle = close > open

var label myLabel = na

var float volumeBullishTotal = 0
if firstSession and bullishCandle
    volumeBullishTotal := volumeBullishTotal + volume
    myLabel = label.new(x=bar_index , y=close, color=color.black,textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_up, size=size.normal,yloc=yloc.belowbar,text = str.tostring(volumeBullishTotal))
  

if  ta.change(time('D'))
    line.new(bar_index, close, bar_index, close * 1.01, extend = extend.both, color = color.blue, style = line.style_dotted, width = 1)

if  ta.change(time('D'))[4]
    line.new(bar_index, close, bar_index, close * 1.01, extend = extend.both, color = color.blue, style = line.style_dotted, width = 1)


plotshape(firstSession and bullishCandle, title="Bullish Candle After Opening", style=shape.triangleup, color=color.green, size=size.small)

However, this code adds the volume of all bullish candles in the first session to the total volume, and I only want to add the volume of candles within that session. Each "session" refers to 4 candles starting from the first candle of the day.
This is the result of the code above

what i want

sory if it's hard to understand, my English isn't good
